# Adicionar elementos de um array para outros arrays

Tags: javascript

Quero adicionar 3 elementos em  cada array vazio de preferencia usando o metodo splice com a condição de que quando data1 tiver 3 elementos ele salta para data2 e adiciona 3 elementos  e quando data2 tiver 3 elementos ele salta para data3 e adiciona até o arr.length for igual a 0. Isso era o que eu queria dizer desde ontem mas sou um novato nesse mundo. Eu sei que não é mto dificil mas eu ja tentei e não consegui.
Mil desculpas a todos que ja responderam a minha pergunta.

O que eu quero será criar uma função para eu poder adicionar os elementos aos 3 arrays vazios ao mesmo tempo.Exatamente eu não quero copiar os elementos do arr eu quero pegar de um array e adicionar aos arrays vazios. por exemplo pego os primeiros 3 indices e adiciono no array1, pego 3 indices e adiciono no array2, pego os ultimos 3 indices e adiciono no array3 mas tudo ao mesmo tempo.

eu quero criar um jogo de cartas simples mas com imagens por isso tenho esse array de imagens e as divs com class diferentes representando cada jogador como eu não consegui passar as imagens directamente para as divs eu resolvi criar 4 arrays para cada jogador mas aí tb tive problema pk n consegui implementar o loop. No jogo tenho que baralhar as cartas, dar as cartas, prever as jogadas, somar o valor das cartas será que posso fazer com javascript? Na sua opinião qual a melhor maneira de fazer?

```
var arr = [];

arr[0]='<img class="images" src="1.jpg">';      
arr[1]='<img class="images" src="2.jpg">';
arr[2]='<img class="images" src="3.jpg">';
arr[3]='<img class="images" src="4.jpg">';
arr[4]='<img class="images" src="5.jpg">';
arr[5]='<img class="images" src="6.jpg">';
arr[6]='<img class="images" src="7.jpg">';
arr[7]='<img class="images" src="8.jpg">';
arr[8]='<img class="images" src="9.jpg">';
arr[9]='<img class="images" src="10.jpg">';
arr[10]='<img class="images" src="11.jpg">';
arr[11]='<img class="images" src="12.jpg">';
```

O resultado seria esse:

js

```
var data1 = ['elemento1','elemento2','elemento3'];
var data2 = ['elemento4','elemento5','elemento6'];
var data3 = ['elemento7','elemento8','elemento9'];
var data4 = ['elemento10','elemento11','elemento12'];
```

html

```
<div id="geral" >

    <div id="posi1" class="div_um"></div>   
    <div id="posi2" class="div_dois"></div> 
    <div id="posi3" class="div_tres"></div>
    <div id="posi4" class="div_quatro"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer? está pouco claro. Como assim "não quero fazer uma cópia"?

Comment: Se explicares também o contexto podemos ajudar na maneira melhor de fazer o que precisas.

Comment: o que eu quero será criar uma função para eu poder adicionar os elementos aos 3 arrays vazios ao mesmo tempo.Exatamente eu não quero copiar os elementos do arr eu quero pegar de um array e adicionar aos arrays vazios. por exemplo pego os primeiros 3 indices e adiciono no array1, pego  3 indices e adiciono no array2, pego os ultimos 3 indices e adiciono no array3 mas tudo ao mesmo tempo. teoricamente eu sei como se faz mas na prática não consegui por estou pedindo ajuda de vcs.

Comment: magestik: eu ainda gostava de deixar mais uma resposta mas gostava que explicasses de onde vêm essas imagens (isto é se as crias à mão ou como a `arr` é preenchida) e também como vais usar `data1`, `data2` e `data3`. Sabendo isso posso deixar uma sugestão de código/lógica a usar.

Comment: Sérgio eu estou a aprender javascript e nao sei se vou lhe explicar corretamente pk ha termos que eu desconheço. Mas é assim essas imagens vem de .../imagens que depois serão inseridas em uma div atraves do data1, então data1 corresponde a uma div, data2 corresponde a uma div e data1 corresponde a uma div. Mas eu não me expliquei direito por isso está dificil de entender.

Comment: magestik: ok, e essas divs já existem no HTML? podes colocar um exemplo do código? assim podias fazer um loop sobre essas imagens que iria distribuílas diretamente dentro de cada div. Só precisamos perceber qual o código dessas divs. Se têm uma classe específica ou um parente comum.

Comment: Vou lhe explicar qual é o meu objectivo com isto tudo, eu quero criar um jogo de cartas simples mas com imagens por isso tenho esse array de imagens e as divs com class diferentes representando cada jogador como eu não consegui passar as imagens directamente para as divs eu resolvi criar 4 arrays para cada jogador mas aí tb tive problema pk n consegui implementar o loop. No jogo tenho que baralhar as cartas, dar as cartas, prever as jogadas, somar o valor das cartas será que posso fazer com javascript? Na sua opinião qual a melhor maneira de fazer? eu ainda tou começando, Obrigado.

Comment: Boa! assim já tenho o contexto que pedi. E já tens algum HTML que eu possa usar num exemplo na minha resposta? ou estás a começar do zero? Os outros passos que vás tendo dificuldade vai perguntando que a gente ajuda.

Comment: Olha podes usar o teu html msm, quero que nos exemplos comentes o codigo pk me interessa perceber msm o codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um ponto de partida podia ser este exemplo que fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/s4Lbmgp9/

No fundo usa como base as divs que referiste, e dentro de cada iteração dessas divs tens um ciclo `for` que corre `3` vezes. A cada iteração desse `for` dentro do `.each()` ele gera novo HTML para ser incluído nas divs.

Neste exemplo ([que referi em cima](http://jsfiddle.net/s4Lbmgp9/)) ele usa um sprite que [encontrei aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18500801/2256325) mas se já tens fundo para as imagens podes ignorar.

Se tens um array com todas as cartas (eventualmente já sorteadas) então preencher essas 4 divs com essas cartas é ainda mais simples. Podes usar assim (uma versão simplificada do exemplo em cima):

```
$('#geral > div').each(function (i) {
    var html = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        html += '<div class="carta" style="background-position: ' + cartas[i + j] + '"></div>';
       // ou se tiveres HTML dentro dessa array simplesmente:
       // html += cartas[i + j];
    }
    this.innerHTML = html;
});
```

**Exemplo live: http://jsfiddle.net/2acv5m36/**

Repara que no exemplo estou a usar as posições na array. Pode ser que tenhas os `url` das imagens na array, aí tens de fazer uma pequena adaptação em relação ao meu exemplo. Mas tem em conta que um sprite só carrega uma vez, fazendo o carregamento da página bem mais leve.

Comment: bom com o teu exemplo ja tenho mta coisa para estudar e começar agora a duvida será como eu comparo o valor entre duas cartas para saber qual delas vale mais, se souberes algum exemplo podes me indicar

Comment: @magestik uma boa idiea seria fazeres o jogo todo sem pensar na parte gráfica. Ou seja, criar a lógica no código com arrays e objetos para cada carta. Assim o podes perguntar aqui sobre os passos que tentaste mas não consegues dar sozinho. E no final juntas a parte gráfica. Se não vais estar a começar pelo fim.

Answer (score 2):

Com base nas suas informaçoes se ao inves de `data1, data2, data3` usar somente um array com todas as `data's` o metodo abaixo pode resolver o seu problema:

```
        var arr = [];

        arr[0]='<img class="images" src="1.jpg">';      
        arr[1]='<img class="images" src="2.jpg">';
        arr[2]='<img class="images" src="3.jpg">';
        arr[3]='<img class="images" src="4.jpg">';
        arr[4]='<img class="images" src="5.jpg">';
        arr[5]='<img class="images" src="6.jpg">';
        arr[6]='<img class="images" src="7.jpg">';
        arr[7]='<img class="images" src="8.jpg">';
        arr[8]='<img class="images" src="9.jpg">'; 

        var dataX = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3) {
            dataX.push(arr.slice(i, i+3));
        }
```

O resultado seria a variavel `dataX` com as arrays de tres elementos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas eu qero saber como adiciono ao mesmo tempo ao em todos os array vazios pk até onde mostras  eu sei fazer. o que eu quero será criar uma função para eu poder adicionar aos 3 arrays vazios ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @magestik sempre o numero de elementos a serem colocados nos arrays serão múltiplos de três?

Comment: quero que sejam adicionados 3 elementos de uma vez.

Comment: @magestik mudei a resposta e isso que você esta precisando?

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua ajuda não era o que eu queria mas consegui com o código que ja tinha aqui.

Comment: Ok @magestik, caso acredite que a solução seria útil para outros usuários, poste ela como resposta da sua pergunta ;)

Comment: @williamhk2 consegui mais informação sobre o problema nos comments e juntei à pergunta. Talvez queiras adaptar a resposta para ele ter 2 respostas válidas como ajuda/referência...

Comment: @Sergio, ok. Hoje mais tarde vou arrumar a resposta, obrigado!